# Scrapy check if image response is 404

Tags: image, file, scrapy

I want to process image URLs, I enabled and configured as [Scrapy Docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html); but what happens if the image URL returns 404 or is redirected. I want to log that, save the failed URLs and the HTTP error/redirect code. Where can I put the code to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely wrong to handle that in the pipleline, because the response would go throw all the middlewares back to your spider then to your pipleline, while your purpose is just logging the failure.

You should build your own middleware to handle any HTTP response code.

By default, scrapy allows responses with statues codes between 200 and 300. You can edit that by listing the statue codes that you would like to receive like this:

```
class Yourspider(spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 302] #add any other code you need
```

Then you should build your middleware and add it to your configuration like this:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myProject.myMiddlewares.CustomSpiderMiddleware': SELECT_NUMBER_SUITS_FOR_YOU,
}
```

in your `CustomSpiderMiddleware` check the status like this:

```
process_spider_input(response, spider):
    if response.status == 404
        #do what ever you want
```

Comment: My purpose is not only logging, I also want to download and process files/images in the case there is no error or redirection.

Comment: if it is not error, the response will go to the spider, but if it is an error (whatever the code is) you can handle it in the middleware

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your custom pipeline, inherit it from the Imagepipeline, then override the item_completed method, as mentioned in the documentation

```
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image_paths'] = image_paths
    return item
```

and lastly in the settings.py add your custom pipeline

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.mypipeline': 100,
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not using Scrapy Items at all.