# How to check the "HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed" with Scrapy?

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy, tor

I using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), and I would like to check the status code before to enter in the parse method.

My code look like:

```
class mywesbite(BaseSpider):
    # Crawling Start
    CrawlSpider.started_on = datetime.now()

    # CrawlSpider
    name = 'mywebsite'
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10

    allowed_domains = ['mywebsite.com']
    pathUrl = "URL/mywebsite.txt"

    # Init
    def __init__(self, local = None, *args, **kwargs):
        # Heritage
        super(mywebsite, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # On Spider Closed
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)


    def start_requests(self):
        return [ Request(url = start_url) for start_url in [l.strip() for l in open(self.pathUrl).readlines()] ]


    def parse(self, response):
       print "==============="
       print response.headers
       print "==============="
       # Selector
       sel = Selector(response)
```

When my proxy is not blocked, I see the response headers, but when my IP is blocked, I just see in the output console this:

> DEBUG: Ignoring response <999 https://www.mywebsite.com>: HTTP status
>   code is not handled or not allowed.

How to check the response header before to enter the parse method?

Edit:
answer: This bug appears when the spider is blocked/banned, by an anti-crawling system. You must use an unblocked proxy system.

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/faq.html?highlight=status#what-does-the-response-status-code-999-means

Comment: thanks for this "auto reply", but in my code, I allready use that.

Comment: check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708729/scrapy-check-if-image-response-is-404/31742171#31742171) on this very-similar question. If you still need help, say please

Comment: thanks, I'll ckeck the link